# Specific query on sqlcommand

Tags: sql, command

hii,can anyone tell what is wrong with this code.??

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TOR_Name FROM TESTCASESTATUS_TABLE WHERE TestCaseID = '" 
        + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'", connection);
SqlDataReader x = command.ExecuteReader();
if (null != x && x.HasRows)
   TestCaseName.Text = Convert.ToString(x["TOR_Name"]);
else 
   TestCaseName.Text = "something";
x.Close();
```

when i debug the code it is even getting into the if conditioon but then it is throwing an error, invalid attempt to read data when no data is present. !!! 
please help/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to issue a [DataReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.read%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) command for the data to be actually loaded into fields, like

```
SqlDataReader x = command.ExecuteReader(); 
if (null != x && x.HasRows) 
{
  x.Read();
  TestCaseName.Text = Convert.ToString(x["TOR_Name"]); 
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Call x.Read() to fetch the first result.